# CollectionView / TableView is considering Popover Arrow direction width and its not centering the position

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipopovercontroller

Added collectionView in popoverPresentationController and collectionview is considering popover arrow direction width as well and due to this collectionview cell is not showing in center.
Added line below to text and given leading and trailing as 20 but its not centered.

```
popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .left
```

[image]

Note: This is happening when i set popover direction as left / right. For up & down its working fine.

Comment: Show some relevant code

Comment: Show a image when its working fine for popover direction up & down